# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir una cadena en Awk?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

Necesito sustituir una cadena en un XML y he hecho esto con Awk:

**OPCION1**

```
cat fichero.xml | awk '{gsub(/cadena1/,"cadena2")}'
```

**OPCION2**

```
awk '{gsub(/cadena1/,"cadena2")}' fichero.xml
```

Pero no me funciona: no me encontraba nada.

Finalmente, lo solucioné usando sed:

```
sed -i 's/cadena1/cadena2/g' fichero.xml
```

¿Qué pasó y qué hice mal en los primeros ejemplos?

Comment: Se entiende tu ejemplo, pero así y todo sería interesante que mostraras un [mcve]. Más que nada porque editar un XML con Awk no es demasiado aconsejable, pues puede cargarse el formato.

Comment: Sí perdón, era un XML de configuración de JBOSS, que debía apuntarlo a servidores distintos. Entonces me hice un sh que reemplaza eso para no andar haciéndolo a mano. Otra opción que había era tener 3 archivos (original, apuntado a 1 y apuntado a 2) e ir copiando y reemplazando en determinada ruta. Pero me pareció demasiado si sólo debía cambiar el servidor en determinada línea. Si no lo edito así, con qué lo editaría?

Comment: Hay una herramienta muy chula llamada [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) para editar XML en UNIX de una forma limpia.

Answer (score 3):

Estabas haciendo correctamente la sustitución pero te faltaba imprimir la salida:

```
awk '{gsub(/cadena1/, "cadena2");print}' fichero.xml
```

Nota: `print` es equivalente `print $0`, que es imprimir el registro completo.

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como correctamente comenta [Patricio en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/148861/83), el comando era correcto, pero era necesario imprimir después el contenido de la línea modificada.

Por tanto, es suficiente con decir:

```
awk '{gsub(/cadena1/, "cadena2")}1' fichero.xml
```

Donde `1` es algo que se ejecutará en cada línea y representa una condición cierta, lo que lanza automáticamente el comando `{print $0}` que imprime la línea actual.

Nótese ademàs que `cat fichero | awk '...'` se puede simplificar con `awk '...'  fichero`, equivalente y más óptimo pues Awk ya sabe leer un fichero dado.

---

Las [funciones de manipulación de cadenas de Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) son muchas y diversas.

En este caso particular, `gsub(patrón, sustitución)` es una función que busca el `patrón` y lo busca tantas veces como puede por "sustitución" en la línea actual. Lo que devuelve es cuántas veces se produjo la sustitución.

```
$ echo "23 23" | awk '{print gsub(23, "bla")}'
2
```

Este contador puede ser interesante para imprimir aquellas líneas que hayan sido modificadas:

```
$ cat fichero
1 - 23
2 - 24
$ awk 'gsub(23, "bla")' fichero
1 - bla
            # la línea 2 - 24 no aparece, pues no se sustituyó nada
```

Comment: Bueno gracias a ambos por la respuesta. En el último de los ejemplos tuyos @fedorqui, reemplaza toda la línea por el bla? no debería reemplazar el 23? o al no colocar las barras sucede eso?
Saludos.

Comment: @Nico.C lo que había era un texto multilínea. Como era algo raro, he sustituido el ejemplo por un archivo.